# I can´t encrypt big files with AES MODE CBC in python "OverflowError size does not fit in an int "

Tags: python, encryption

My script Works very well with light files, but with heavy files like (ISO FILES). In fact, when my script is running to encrypt a large file (I did a test encrypting a 4gb-size Windows ISO) it took a long time to process, then the command window no longer responded and finally I got the error: "OverflowError size does not fit in an int " I don´t know Why

I use AES ALGORITHM with CBC MODE and IV:

```
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES  
    from Crypto.Hash import SHA256 
    from Crypto import Random 
    
    
    
    def password_hash(pasw_):
        p = SHA256.new(pasw_.encode("utf-8"))
        return p.digest()
    ##################################################
    def padding_data(data):
        return data+ b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(data) % AES.block_size) 
    ##################################################
    def encrypt_data(key,clean_data):
        complete_block_data = padding_data(clean_data)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return cipher_data 
    ##################################################
    def decrypt_data(key, cipher_data):
        iv = cipher_data[:AES.block_size]
        decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        clear_data =  decipher.decrypt(cipher_data[AES.block_size:])
        return clear_data.rstrip(b"\0")

##################################################
```

These are the main functions from my script, but I really want to know:
How could I encrypt heavy files with a size more than 3 GB with this algorithm.

I would be very grateful if someone helps thanks

Comment: Edit the question to explain "doesn't work".

Comment: Ok, I already did it

Comment: I guess that you use a 32 bit variant of Python. Using 64 bit (if supported by the OS) can help. But best portable way would be to process the data in chunks instead of the whole file at once.

Comment: Can you explain me about chunks?, how could I do that ? please

Comment: Chunking means splitting. See an example here (scroll down to the end of the page): https://nitratine.net/blog/post/python-encryption-and-decryption-with-pycryptodome/#file-example-proof